# Why is the problem occuring in my python if-else statement?

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I am making a bot like a AI in python

In this code I want any condition to run when I entered a `input`.

Whenever a am typing anything I am expecting to `else:` to be true but everytime the 3rd `elif` is being true like it's an `else`

I had tried changing position of the `elif` statment so some other statement is executing

Actually my code is very big it's just a part from it

No error msg for indentation error:

The code starts from here:

---

```
if "time now" in command:
        print(prefix , time)

elif "date today" in command:
        print(prefix ,  date)
    
elif "quit" or "exit" in command:
        print(prefix , "Good bye user !!! ")
        print("0====[]::::::::::>")
        exit()
else:
        print(prefix, "I am unable to understand you ): ")
        print( "Type the command correctly ! !")
        print()
        return AQassistant()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
if "quit":
    print("True")
```

Output: `True`

Your elif should instead be:
`elif "quit" in command or "exit" in command`

Otherwise the condition will always evaluate to true.

Alternatively, you can do:

```py
command = "quit"

if any(cmd in command for cmd in ["quit", "exit"]):
    print("quit/exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
elif "quit" or "exit" in command:
```

is same as writing

```
elif ("quit") or ("exit" in command):
```

Due to [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - `in` is more sticky than `or`. As "quit" is non-empty str it is considered to be truthy in python, so above is always `True` as one part of `or` is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

`"quit"` is always `True`!

`"quit" or "exit" in command` is the same as `True or "exit" in command`. The same as simply `True`.

Any empty string is `False`

All other strings are `True`

So, your code should be something like this:

```
if "time now" in command:
        print(prefix , time)

elif "date today" in command:
        print(prefix ,  date)
    
elif "quit" in command or "exit" in command:
        print(prefix , "Good bye user !!! ")
        print("0====[]::::::::::>")
        exit()
else:
        print(prefix, "I am unable to understand you ): ")
        print( "Type the command correctly ! !")
        print()
        return AQassistant()
```